# What is the difference between Mouse.OverrideCursor and this.Cursor

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the difference between using

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait
```

and

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait.
```

which one is correct ?
As I am using `WPF` and `C#`.

Answer (score 18):

The main difference is that [`Mouse.OverrideCursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.overridecursor.aspx) will set the mouse cursor for the whole application while [`this.Cursor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.cursor.aspx) will set it only for that specific `FrameworkElement`.

So it will depend what you want to do.

If you want to show the wait cursor for the entire application use `Mouse.OverrideCursor`, but if you only want to show the wait cursor over a specific part of the application use `this.Cursor`.